# Cannot decode Base64 String to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, base64

I am trying to decode Base64 string image to `Bitmap`, but it always returns `null`.

Here is my code:

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmap(String encode) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        try { 
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encode, Base64.DEFAULT);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            return bm;
        }

        return bm;
    }
```

Comment: post your code it will be helpful

Comment: Here is my code to: public static Bitmap getBitmap(String encode) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encode, Base64.DEFAULT);

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            return  bm;
        }
        return bm;
    }

Answer (score 0):

For me this code works:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Base64.decode(B64.BASEFILE, Base64.DEFAULT), 0, Base64.decode(B64.BASEFILE, Base64.DEFAULT).length);
ImageView iw = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
iw.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

I'm compiling this on API 22.

Comment: same as my functtion